# Is an accumulation point $x$ for a sequence $s=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ also point of $\mathrm{der}\{x_0,...,x_n,...\}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let be $s=(x_n)_\mathbb{N}$ a sequence in $X$, so we define

$$
x\in X\text{ accumulation point for } s\Longleftrightarrow(\forall U_x\in\mathcal{U}(x)\wedge\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\exists m\ge n:x_m\in U_x
$$

well using this definition I ask me if an accumulation point $x\in X$ for $s$ is such that  $x\in\text{der}\{x_0,\ldots,x_n,\ldots\}$, that is

$$\forall U_x\in\mathcal{U}(x):(U_x\cap\{x_0,....,x_n,...\})\setminus\{x\}\neq\varnothing
$$

It seems to me that if $x\in X$ is an accumulation point for $s$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n\neq x$ it is that $x\in\mathrm{der}\{x_0,\ldots,x_n,\ldots\}$, but if it is the contrary what's happen?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n=0$ $\>(n\geq0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boring example in any metric space $(X,d)$: take $x_n =p$ for all $n$, with $ p \in X$. That $p$ is an accumulation point is trivial (it's even a limit) but the set of values is $\{p\}$ which has no limit points (empty derived set).

Also consider $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,\ldots$ which has $1$ as an accumulation point and the range has no limit points again (in the reals, usual topology).

If the sequence is injective ($n \neq m \to x_n \neq x_m$) we can show that an accumulation point of it must be a limit point of its range in any $T_1$ space.

Comment: Anyway a limit point $x$ for a sequence $s=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an accumulation point for it, really?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro some text books call it a limit point, as it is the limit of a subsequence. But limit point of a set is a different notion.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted ask if the point $x$ is the limit of the sequence $s=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},$ that is $\forall U_x\in\mathcal{U}(x)\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}: x_n\in U_x \forall n\ge n_0$, then it is an accumulation point for $s$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes that is trivial. In a Hausdorff space a sequence has at most one limit but can have very many accumulation points.

Comment: Okay, so if the point $x$ is the limit of the sequence $s=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ so it is an accumulation point for $s$ (as before we defined it), that is $(\forall U_x\in\mathcal{U}(x)\wedge\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\exists m\ge n:x_m\in U_x$, really?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes. The proof is trivial.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!